# Can anyone please clarify my doubts regarding tourist Visa to Australia - Business Stream

Tags: australia, business-travel

I am from India and been working (as a graphic designer) for a real estate company in Australia from last couple of years. I have never been outside India. I am planning to visit Australia this Christmas holidays. I am suggested to go for 600 tourist visa - business stream. I have all the necessary documents from my side to upload. I just need some help regarding the document which are needed from the real estate company. Someone gave me list of these documents below:

- Invitation Letter
- Residence Proof
- Business Cards
- ITR (2 Years)
- Ownership Proof
- Notice of Assessments
- Letter head ( Mentioning I am working for them in their team from last 2 years )
- Company Registration Document
- ID Proof of Person sending Sponsor
- Bank Statements (2 Years)
- Passport Photos
- Contact details of the inviter
- Hotel Booking for Stay

Do we really need all this from the real estate company? or just an invitation letter to a meeting, with contact details and IDs will work?

Also where can i find format of letter of invitation? Also will it be sent on their standard letterhead or they need to visit embassy or agent in order to send it over?

Comment: Tourist and business streams are two different things. What are you actually planning to do in Australia? Just visit as a tourist? Visit family? Work for your employer? Meet your employer? A combination?

Comment: You will need to clarify (a) why you are coming to Australia; and (b) the exact nature of the contractual relationship with the real estate company, i.e. is it a contract *for* service (in which case they are your client, not your employer), or a contract *of* service.  Otherwise the answers given here could be dangerously wrong and your visa application will be refused.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to visit Australia for holidays, you need to apply as a normal tourist visa ([600 - Tourist Stream](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Tourist-Stream-document-checklist)). The link provides a list of documents but in summary you need to show the following:

- A valid travel document (a passport) that is valid for the duration of your trip.
- How will you support your trip? This includes bank statements to show you have income and more importantly the trip is not an undue burden on you.
- What is the guarantee that you will return? For this you provide documents such as an employment letter, a letter authorizing your leave, if your are married and have family depending on you, significant property, etc.

Now, as your employer is in Australia its difficult to provide the proof of intent to return ("incentive and authority to return to your home country") - they can help you by offering to act as a sponsor for your trip. In this case, it will be a *person* and not a *company*.

The [600 - Business Visitor Stream](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/600-/Visitor-visa-(subclass-600)-Business-Visitor-Stream-document-checklist) is for those people traveling to Austrialia for non-tourist activities thus you need to provide supporting documents as stated in the "Additional Documents" section:

> - Evidence of why you need to visit Australia on business, such as:
>
>   - a letter of invitation from the host organisation in Australia
>   - conference registration details
>   - a letter from your employer stating the reasons for your visit
>   - your itinerary, with contact details of the business parties involved.
> - Your educational or professional qualifications.
> - Your current employment and your role during your visit to Australia.
> - Details of previous contacts with Australian businesspeople or organisations.
> - Documents to show that the company you work for is an actively operating business, such as a business registration certificate or annual report.​

Applying for the Business Stream while actually going for tourism is deception and if caught, you may be banned from visiting Australia.

I would recommend applying for the tourist stream, and ask if someone from the company can offer to sponsor your trip.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for taking out time to help me out.

Comment: 1- Letter of invitation - Do it need to be just a formal letter drafted on their letterhead? Or is it something that needs to be prepared by a lawyer or agent/agency/embassy? What info should it contain ?

2- Do they need to book my air tickets and hotel tickets aswell? can i stay at my frnds home who is in sydney once i get there?

3- Details of previous contacts with Australian businesspeople or organisations. - For this can i share contact of my other freelance clients in Australia?

Comment: @CBPrabhakar again, what are you actually planning to do while in Australia? Are you coming as a tourist, or are you coming to meet your employer/customer, or both? What is your actual relationship with your "employer"? I'm guessing you are actually a freelancer or have your own company rather than actually being an employee? Do you have customers in other countries? Do you have anything that shows your intent to return (family, property...)? Coming to Australia for business over Christmas is going to appear incredibly fishy!

Comment: @jcaron, to attend a meeting in that company. would like to explore too once i am there. you can say customer as i am working with them from last 2 years. i have my company registered in india and yes i do work for them as a freelancer from last 2 years. yes i do have customers in other countries, and more customers in Australia as-well. yes family, propetry, business,

Comment: @jcaron , there is a Form 54 family composition, there is a place for signature of witness. whose signature can go there? any special procedure to follow?